# How to manually create a new session in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am working on a symfony project which is made of 2 applications (frontend & backend) and I have been asked to manually create a second session in the backend so that the administrator could access user data (the frontend) from the backend without logging in.
I've set different names in factory.yml so that each application has its own cookie.
Basicalyy, I need to retrieve a user from the backend, manually create the frontend cookie without destroying the backend session then redirect to the frontend.
I've tried the following code but this doesn't work :

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('some_attribute');
$session = new sfSessionStorage();
$option  = array(
    'session_name' => 'frontend_session_name'
); 
$session->initialize($options);
// some code to push the user in the new cookie

$this->redirect('https://frontend.php');
```

I haven't been using symfony for long and must admit that I'm a bit lost here. I know I need to populate the new cookie with the user data but I can't figure out how.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using propel.
edit #2: I've come up with the following solution which does what intended :

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('some_attribute'); //retrieving the user whose data I'd like to access
$currentSessionId = session_id();
session_write_close();
session_name('frontend_session_name');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/culture'] = 'en';
$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/lastRequest'] = time();
$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/authenticated'] = 1;
$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/credentials'] = array('frontend_user');
$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/attributes'] = array(
  'symfony/user/sfUser/attributes' => array(
      'user' => $user
  )
);
session_write_close();
session_name('backend_session_name');
session_id($currentSessionId);
session_start();

$this->redirect('/frontend.php');
```

So I just manually recreated the session and pushed in the necessary data.
Thanks to those who tried to help.

Comment: Could try using the same `session_save_path` for both your apps? This might let you run the same session across both apps. You will just need to protect your backend from being accessed by frontend users.

Comment: Thank you for your help antony, but I need to keep both apps separate. When accessing the frontend, I'd like to trick the app into believing that it's an authenticated user accessing their data while keeping the option to go back to the the backend without logging in. I don't have a choice here. That's the way I've been asked to implement it.

Comment: To keep it simple you should just use the same session cookie (set the same session name in factories.yml) and proctect the backend app with credentials.

Comment: I think also it might be easier to add an option to the session so that the admin "acts as" another user. You will not need a separate session for that. I know Symfony 2.3 offers this solution out of the box, in Sf 1.4. you have to write it yourself.

Comment: 1ed, I didn't write that part. Switching between apps was handled by credentials initially, but that was changed and now I have to find a work around.

Comment: Thank you Michal Trojanowski. I may give a go to your solution.

Comment: Well, I've tried Michal Trojanowski's solution but it creates unexpected behaviour due to the fact that there are sessions variables that share the same name in both applications. As there are many of them and I didn't write them all, going through the entire code is not an option unfortunately. What I need here is create a new session manually and push in data needed in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

As sharing a session doesn't seem to be an option for you, I'd suggest:

- creating a unique key for each user, not the id, but a separate string that is hard to guess
- create a module / action on the frontend that accepts the key as a parameter, finds the corresponding user in the database, and logs them in

You could then generate the required links in the backend that an admin can click and be redirected to.

Not very secure, make sure your keys are long. You'd need to add code to prevent brute forcing, and limit access to the action by IP address maybe?

You could also require the key of the admin user, and check that it is valid too, which would make it harder to guess.